# $\lim_{x\to\infty}\int_0^{x} e^{t^2} dt=\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

I want to show that $\lim_{x\to\infty}\int_0^{x} e^{t^2} dt=\infty$. Taylor expansion can help for sure. But I wanted to know if someone knows a nice way of showing the statement without using Taylor?

Comment: How would you do it *using* the Taylor expansion?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$e^{t^{2}} >1$ for $t>0$. So the integral is greater than $x$.

Answer (score 4):

If $x>1$, then\begin{align}\int_0^xe^{t^2}\,\mathrm dt&=\int_0^1e^{t^2}\,\mathrm dt+\int_1^xe^{t^2}\,\mathrm dt\\&\geqslant\int_0^1e^{t^2}\,\mathrm dt+\int_1^xe^t\,\mathrm dt\\&=\int_0^1e^{t^2}\,\mathrm dt+e^x-1\end{align}and $\lim_{x\to\infty}\int_0^1e^{t^2}\,\mathrm dt+e^x-1=\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

Using Taylor expansion and monotone convergence theorem we get

$$\int_0^x e^{t^2}\,dt = \int_0^x \left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{t^{2n}}{n!}\right)\,dt = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \int_0^x\frac{t^{2n}}{n!}\,dt = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^{2n+1}}{n!(2n+1)} \ge x$$